# How to add Meteor.userId() to SimpleSchema via autoValue?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

Inside my libs folder I create collections using SimpleSchema. I want to add the Meteor.userId to some fields via autoValue like this:

```
Collection = new Meteor.Collection('collection');
Collection.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    createdByUser: {
        type: String,
        max: 20,
        autoValue: function() {
            return Meteor.userId();
        }
    }
});
```

When doing this however, I receive the following error:

```
Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.
```

I tried this as well:

```
var userIdentification = Meteor.userId();
Collection = new Meteor.Collection('collection');
Collection.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    createdByUser: {
        type: String,
        max: 20,
        autoValue: function() {
            return userIdentification;
        }
    }
});
```

This will crash my application though:

```
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`userId` information is provided to [`autoValue` by `collection2`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#autovalue) through `this`

> The autoValue option is provided by the SimpleSchema package and is documented there. Collection2 adds the following properties to this for any autoValue function that is called as part of a C2 database operation:
>
> - isInsert: True if it's an insert operation
> - isUpdate: True if it's an update operation
> - isUpsert: True if it's an upsert operation (either upsert() or upsert: true)
> - userId: The ID of the currently logged in user. (Always null for server-initiated actions.)

So your code should read as:

```
Collection = new Meteor.Collection('collection');
Collection.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    createdByUser: {
        type: String,
        max: 20,
        autoValue: function() {
            return this.userId;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `this.userId()` didn't work for me, instead I used `Meteor.user()._id`

Comment: because the correct form is `this.userId` and not `this.userId()`. Furthermore, this is much much much faster than obtaining `Meteor.user()` or `Meteor.userId()` which is also not always available everywhere, namely publish functions